# why does IOS and videojs make multiple calls to pull stream?

Tags: javascript, ios, video-streaming, video.js

I have an mvc webpage with videojs on it streaming an mp4 file. when I run the page from a desktop, and debug the site, I can see that with a desktop view of the page, the video gets called twice for some reason, both calls seems to have a range-request of the entire filesize. this seems strange that its being called twice, but even stranger, if I call this same page from IOS (IPAD), I see 6 calls for the stream. the first two are usually requesting the first two bytes which makes sense based on my knowledge that IOS does this to determine if the stream is seekable. Then it makes 4 more calls to pull the stream each with a range-request of the entire filesize from what I can recall. Anyone know if this is normal for IOS and videojs use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal. the player is probing the file to determine characteristics. It is trying to find the location of the mdat and moov atoms. Even though it asks for the entire file, it will disconnect the TCP session as soon as it has the data it needs to seek with into file.